# Spring MVC : how to check http response status code in a Spring Interceptor?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am doing one application that need to get **http status code** if status code  **404,406 or 500**  i want to redirect specific page 
for that i am using spring Interceptors. In `HandlerInterceptor#postHandle` `HttpServletResponse` parameter but  no `getStatus()` method there how can get status code?

Comment: Which servlet container version are you on. `getStatus` is there if you are on a servlet 3.0 or higher container.

Comment: i am using spring 4.x

Comment: I'm not asking about your spring version I'm asking about your servlet container.

Comment: how can i check my servlet container version i am using tomcat 7.0

Comment: did you try defining error code mapping in web.xml? <error-page>
  <error-code>404</error-code>
  <location>/error</location>
 </error-page>

Comment: Then upgrade your `servlet-api` dependency to 3.0 instead of 2.5 or even lower.

Comment: thanks to @ M. Deinum got solution @Pulkit i will check your solution also